# Not enough storage space is available

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-installer

I have just re-installed a Windows Server 2008 Machine and am trying to get it into production, shipped with SQL Server 2008; the problem is, that it requires an application called: `Windows Installer` recommended is 4.5 or higher, I have went to the Microsoft Website and downloaded the official package but when running I get:

```
Setup Error: 
Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

I then press OK then get presented with:

```
Setup Error
installation did not complete.
```

When viewing Event viewer:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Windows Installer 3.1
Date:          13/04/2013 19:10:25
Event ID:      4373
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DOMAIN CONTROLLED REMOVED
Description:
The description for Event ID 4373 from source Windows Installer 3.1 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Windows
Not enough storage is available to process this command.


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Installer 3.1" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49166">4373</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-13T18:10:25.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>266</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DOMAIN CONTROLLED REMOVED</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Windows</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>Not enough storage is available to process this command.
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

That is when installing Windows Installer 3.1

---

Attempting Windows Installer 4.5 Returns:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        NtServicePack
Date:          13/04/2013 19:06:42
Event ID:      4373
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DOMAIN CONTROLLED REMOVED
Description:
The description for Event ID 4373 from source NtServicePack cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Windows
Not enough storage is available to process this command.


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="NtServicePack" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49166">4373</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-13T18:06:42.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>262</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DOMAIN CONTROLLED REMOVED</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Windows</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>Not enough storage is available to process this command.
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is most likely bogus. Note that Windows Server 2008 [*already comes with Installer 4.0*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so there should be no need ever for installing 3.1 anew from the redistributable package.

You should try re-registring the Windows Installer version which is already present on your system:

1. check if the value of "ImagePath" in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSIServer` contains a valid reference to the msiexec.exe of your system (e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /V`)
2. start the machine in safe mode and run `msiexec /regserver` as Administrator to re-register it in the system

(taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324516/en-us)

Comment: SQL Server 2008 requires 4.5, so regardless; this will still throw an error with installer 4.0 because it's under the necessary revision

Comment: @DarylGill you should try re-registering it at any rate. Since the 3.1 installer could not detect the presence of a newer version, something seems to be badly broken. Also worth checking if the "Windows Installer" service entry is present and in a non-disabled state.

Comment: Give me a minute to try option 1

Comment: `%systemroot%\system32\msiexec /V`  is the entry and to double check that wild card WINKEY + R and typing `%systemroot%` directs to: `C:\Windows`

Comment: After running option two, it allowed me to download the .msu package to upgrade to 4.5 which allows my SQL Server to be installed

Comment: @DarylGill glad to hear it helped. Thank you for reporting back.

Comment: Little weird that windows installer is disabled on my system.. Never would have considered somethin like that

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the entry is `C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /V`, but not simply `C:\Windows\System32\msiexec /V`. I changed - added ".exe" and it worked!